What is the purpose of the DefaultValueFrom attribute in GeneXus Pattern instance XML definitions?
In GeneXus Patterns, within the XML definition of an instance, elements of the Attribute type (under ElementType) have two XML attributes: DefaultValue and DefaultValueFrom. Both are strings.
I need to load default values into an instance, and I think the DefaultValueFrom attribute might be useful for this, but I couldn't find any documentation about it.
Does anyone know what it is for or how it is used?
An example of xml:
    <ElementType Name="Service" Caption="Service ({0})" CaptionParameters="name" KeyAttribute="name" Icon="StructureLevel" IconResource="Concepto.Patterns.WW3L.Resources.Images,Concepto.Patterns.WW3L"  >
        <Attributes>
            <Attribute Name="name" Type="string" NotNull="true" DefaultValueFrom="" />

